# How to reverse geocode?

Tags: iphone

I my iPhone application I have to find the city and country name of current location. How it can be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MKReverseGeocoder: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKReverseGeocoder_Class/Reference/Reference.html

MKReverseGeocoderDelegate:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKReverseGeocoderDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

You need MapKit for this.

## Example <sup>(given myCoor)</sup>

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
  MKReverseGeocoder *rg = [[MKReverseGeocoder alloc] initWithCoordinate:myCoor];
  rg.delegate = self;
  [rg start];
}

- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFindPlacemark:(MKPlacemark *)placemark {
  NSLog(@"%@, %@", placemark.locality, placemark.country);
}

- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
  NSLog(@"%@", error);
}
```

(In example I didn't care about memleaks but as I see from your profile you're a Java developer (where memory management is no problem), I recommend you do.)

Comment: Hi, I will and let you know. Thanks

Comment: If you want to use the data, do that in `reverseGeocoder:didFindPlacemark:` and be sure to show the user an error in `reverseGeocoder:didFailWithError:`. These two methods get called automatically.

Comment: ...to elaborate on the memory management, it is very important that you call release rg (the reverse geocoder) when you're done with it. Not sure 'not caring' about memory leaks is the right attitude on StackOverflow, given how often code gets copied and pasted without people bothering to read the stuff below it!

Comment: Update: MKReverseGeocoder is deprecated in iOS 5.0, moving on to Core Location. Use CLGeocoder Instead.