# How to retrieve the address from a location returned by Core Location

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, mapkit, core-location

Is there a way to turn a longitude/latitude location (as returned by Core Location) into an address (street and city)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reverse geocode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701113/how-to-reverse-geocode)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best way is using reverse geocoding, which is available in `CLGeocoder` class. To get human readable address from geoposition, you have to use `reverseGeocodeLocation` method.

Here is small sample:

```
-(NSString *)getAddressFromLocation:(CLLocation *)location {
    NSString *address;
    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:location completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error)
     {
         if(placemarks && placemarks.count > 0)
         {
             CLPlacemark *placemark= [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];

             address = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@,%@ %@", [placemark subThoroughfare],[placemark thoroughfare],[placemark locality], [placemark administrativeArea]];

             NSLog(@"%@",address);
         }

     }];

    [geocoder release];
    return address;
}
```

Comment: This returns a invalid CFStringRef. Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks!!

Comment: I got "Assign a variable inside a Block to a variable outside a Block" error, but I was able to fix it by doing like this, "__block NSString *address;"

Comment: why dont you use completion instead a block variable?

Answer (score 2):

Rough Swift 3 implementation using closures:

```
import CoreLocation

func getAddressFrom(location: CLLocation, completion:@escaping ((String?) -> Void)) {
    let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
    geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { (placemarks, error) in
        if let placemark = placemarks?.first,
            let subThoroughfare = placemark.subThoroughfare,
            let thoroughfare = placemark.thoroughfare,
            let locality = placemark.locality,
            let administrativeArea = placemark.administrativeArea {
            let address = subThoroughfare + " " + thoroughfare + ", " + locality + " " + administrativeArea

            placemark.addressDictionary

            return completion(address)

        }
        completion(nil)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
getAddressFrom(location: location) { (address) in
    print(address)
}
```

You can also look at `placemark.addressDictionary`, which is dictionary containing the Address Book keys and values for the placemark.  These keys are defined in the Address Book framework.